# Limit on file name length in bash

Tags: linux, bash, file, maxlength

The following questions are meant for bash and linux only:

1. Is there a limit on the number of characters in the absolute path name of a file?
2. Is there a limit on the number of characters for the filename (without extension) only?

If so, what might these limits be? How can I access them in case they are system specific?

Comment: I always wondered how people could hit limits like filename length. what are you doing?

Comment: @yi_H: LOL! nothing, just writing a big file name (absolute path) to a file and reading the name from it. The reading takes place within asterisk, and I must figure out how many characters I need to read. This question sprang as an aside from there.

Comment: This smells so much like homework...but in the end it belongs on ServerFault, SuperUser or Unix&Linux.

Comment: @Bobby: If it were homework, I would have labelled it so.

Comment: @Sriram: Yes, I thought so. That was just a conclusion, no insult intended.

Comment: @Bobby: not to worry, i did not take your comment as an insult or anything of that sort.. cheers!

Comment: @KarolyHorvath I was only trying in my code to code information on how data were generated into the filename, but failed to write `im_syn_profile_BT,Radar94Z,_to_IWC,_chans1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,_noise1.000000e-01,1.000000e-01,1.000000e-01,1.000000e-01,1.000000e-01,1.000000e-01,1.000000e-01,1.000000e-01,1.000000e-01,1.000000e-01,1.000000e-01,1.000000e-01,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,_0.mat` :(

Comment: Bash, of course, simply inherits whatever limit the OS it runs on imposes.

Comment: @KarolyHorvath Well, inside an ecryptfs-mounted home folder I am hitting a name limit (`getconf NAME_MAX $HOME`) of 143. I'm hitting the limit all the time.

Comment: @KarolyHorvath I am generating some files (one per test case) and I want to see how much metadata I can fit in their filenames. The alternative would be to create a separate metadata file for each test case and concatenate them. (Nothing against the alternative, but I want to see if I can get away with it).

Answer (score 82, accepted):

It depends very much on the filesystem. For the ext FS (currently the most used on Linux):

- max filename length: 255 bytes
- max path length: none

The extension is not something the FS is aware of, it 255 bytes, extension included (you can have file names without any extensions).

[Here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_file_systems) is a more exhaustive list of these limits, per FS.

There can also be extensions to your file system that can change your maximum length as well. For example, eCryptFS which uses part of the lower file name to keep metadata and limits the file name to a maximum length of 143 characters. See [Ubuntu eCryptFS launchpad](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ecryptfs/+bug/344878) entry.

Comment: There is also the linux kernel imposed limit [PATH_MAX](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9449241/where-is-path-max-defined-in-linux) defined in linux/limits.h, which is usually 4096 char's. The last character is reserved for the string terminator null character.

Comment: Also each application may have its own limit that it imposes.

Comment: In case someone has any doubts: combining this response to [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6571693/982542) on a `ecryptfs`, I have been able to verify the bug is still unresolved (though reading the bug itself make me think it will never be resolved)

Comment: @BeowulfNode42 But beware that `PATH_MAX` is not a fixed limit for many file operations, see https://askubuntu.com/a/1169977 And also that earlier definitions did not make it clear whether the null terminator is included, so allocating e.g. `PATH_MAX + 1` is safer.

Answer (score 44):

In a temp directory, run:

```
num=1
while [ true ]
do 
   if ! touch $(printf "%${num}s"  | tr ' ' 'a')
   then
       echo $num
       break
   fi
   ((num++))
done
```

and I get:

```
touch: cannot touch `aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa': File name too long
256
```

which means my limit is 255.

Comment: I get 144, which means my limit is 143. Why so short!? I'm running Ubuntu 16.04 LTS 64-bit.

Comment: @GabrielStaples you are probably using eCryptFS.

Btw, this answer is very useful. Thanks!

Comment: `while [ true ]` is a common antipattern; it works, but not for the reason you probably think. `while [ false ]` would work equally well; you are testing whether the string between `[` and `]` is not empty, which of course it isn't. The proper idiomatic way to write an endless loop is simply `while true`

Answer (score 17):

On Mac OS X 10.6.7:

```
man getconf
getconf NAME_MAX /   # 255 bytes
getconf PATH_MAX /   # 1024 bytes

# check file path length with wc before using touch, mkdir, etc.
echo '/very/lllooooonnnnnggggg/file/path.txt' | wc -c
```

Comment: For what it's worth, `getconf` is in [POSIX](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/getconf.html) so definitely not MacOS only.

Comment: Actually, the usage is identical; the code in this answer checks the limit for the root file system.

Answer (score 14):

<sup>I refer to other answers, please upvote them.</sup>

On Linux, filename and pathname lengths depends on :

- [file-system limits](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_file_systems#Limits) as stated by [eugene y](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6571543/938111) and [ncmathsadist](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6571554/938111) ;
- constant defined in `linux/limits.h` before compilation as stated by [Michael Aaron Safyan](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6571596/938111) and later [David Balažic](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16637028/938111) has pointed to [a similar question](https://serverfault.com/a/306726/106052).

To dynamically get these properties in [bash](/questions/tagged/bash):

- Create a filename (or pathname) longer and longer as explained by [dogbane](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6571693/938111)
- Use the command `getconf` as proposed by [tim](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6582758/938111) that is also available on Linux:

  ```
  $ getconf NAME_MAX /mnt/sda2/
  255
  $ getconf PATH_MAX /mnt/sda3/
  4096
  ```

Answer (score 9):

The Single UNIX Specification mentions `NAME_MAX` and `PATH_MAX` constants in [limits.h](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/basedefs/limits.h.html) that can be read with [pathconf](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/pathconf.html). However, this is very filesystem dependent, and you are unlikely to hit such a limit.

NOTE: As a programmer, you should not hard-code these limits. You should use dynamic allocation, so that it will always work so long as the underlying system allows for whatever you are doing.

Answer (score 4):

> 1. Is there a limit on the number of characters in the absolute path name of a file?

Yes, there is.

See [answer by sfp](https://serverfault.com/a/306726/105831) at the question [Filename length limits on linux?](https://serverfault.com/questions/9546/filename-length-limits-on-linux) on server**fault**

In short:

```
#define PATH_MAX        4096    /* # chars in a path name including nul */
```

And for:

> 2. Is there a limit on the number of characters for the filename (without extension) only?

in the same linked answer:

```
#define NAME_MAX         255    /* # chars in a file name */
```

Comment: Thanks for the link to the similar question on serverfault. But I do not think the answer from sft is pretty good. I prefer the answer from @WerkkreW giving a good link: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_file_systems#Limits

Comment: That link is about file systems, not bash or linux as stated in the question. For example it lists no limit defined for ext3 file system, but linux has a limit of 4096 (regardless of filesystem).

Comment: I agree with you :-) Thank you for pointing to a similar question +1 :-) Let's say it depends on both : FS and `linux/limits.h`. But the ultimate answer would be something like `cat /proc/sys/fs/file-max` or... `getconf NAME_MAX /` ... Yes last command is the good one ... and [tim](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6582758/938111) as found it before me. Cheers

Comment: `PATH_MAX` is not always the real limit, see: https://askubuntu.com/a/1169977

Answer (score 4):

FYI, on Docker, the filename limit is currently [242 characters](https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/1413).

Answer (score 3):

It depends on the filesystem used. For example, ext4 has maximum filename length of 256 bytes and unlimited pathname length.

See [Comparison of file systems](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_file_systems) for more.

Comment: Damn, you got me on this one.

Answer (score 2):

This is not bash-dependent; it's OS dependent.  On a mac, its 0xff for a filename and 0x400 or so for a path name.  Ubuntu 9 had a limit of 144 characters for file names.

I have found this link in [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_file_systems).   It tells path and filename limits for numerous file systems.

Comment: The mac involved has HFS+ on it and the Unix machine is ext4.