# Iterating and executing Awk function over multiple input files and producing different output files

Tags: python, bash, perl, shell, awk

I have hundreds of large text files as **test1, test2, test3, ....., test100** in a folder.

Each of these test files has text entries. My job is to read each text file and then split each test$i files on every blank line in each text files and create various new text files.

For example: If test1.txt has 3 blank lines then the number of files generated will be 4 text files with names of each new files as **test1.1,  test1.2, test1.3, test1.4**  { Reference = [Splitting large text file on every blank line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33294986/splitting-large-text-file-on-every-blank-line)}

I did this for a single file and it perfectly works and I get various files as **test1.1, test1.2, test1.3, test1.4**

```
awk -v RS= '{print > ("test1." NR ".txt")}' test1
```

But when I tried doing this for multiple files in loop,

```
for i in {1..100}; do awk -v RS= '{print > ("test" $i "." NR ".txt")}' test$i; done
```

It does not work. I am wondering, why the values of $i does not passes into the awk function and it does not print the different empty separated individual files as  **test1.1, test1.2, test1.3...... test2.1, test2.2 ... so on...**

One issue, which I am seeing is: "*File name too long*".
Reference Link: [Limit on file name length in bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6571435/limit-on-file-name-length-in-bash)

Kindly help me to understand and fix it or some better approach for this task.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using awk only:

```
$ awk -v RS= '{f=(FILENAME "." FNR ".txt"); print > f; close(f)}' test*
```

Comment: Yes. Thanks. This works absolutely fine but I am wondering, if I need to export the output f=(FILENAME "." FNR ".txt") in different file location lets say in folder Desktop/tmp, How to go ahead?

Comment: `f=("/path/to/" FILENAME "." FNR ".txt")`